# What NoSQL database is good for complex many to many relationships?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, neo4j, relationship, nosql

My startup project require complex data structure, which must be ready for geolocation and fulltext search. The information in the database are added by two different types of users, who together build a complex relationship network.

For a better understanding of my questions, here is a simple diagram that shows this relationship:

[image]

My first choice was MongoDB and Elasticsearch, but I noticed the problem of multiplication of the same data. Further planning, we concluded that for certain parts of the application need ACID transactions possibilities.

What NoSQL database is good for complex many to many relationships?

What would be a good choice for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph database like Neo4j is perfect for that.

If you need features of a document database like MongoDB, but with Neo4j under the hood, try Structr: http://de.slideshare.net/AxelMorgner/neo4j-as-document-database http://structr.org

(Disclaimer: I'm the project inititator of Structr)

Comment: Also to clarify, you may still need/want to use elasticsearch for full-text search type behavior.  Also, neo4j supports ACID transactions.

Comment: Neo4j has Lucene built-in for full-text indexing, supporting a number of index-based query types.

In addition, Structr provides indexing of empty fields, numerical/date range queries, case-sensitive and -insensitive search.

All index operations are fully bound to transactions, so the indexes are within the ACID scope, which is much better than trying to integrate different databases and fight with sync issues.

Comment: Fair enough, but to clarify the reason that I didn't even think about the Lucene indexes is because they're complicated to use (part of why they're called legacy indexes)

Comment: That's true. :-) And that's why we have fully encapsulated them in Structr, so users don't have to care about it. For plain Neo4j, you have also the schema/automatic indexes which can be easily maintained via Cypher.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic for SO since they are, as in this case, normally opioninated

Comment: @Sammaye  you are right i move my question to Quora.  Axel & Brain. Thanks.  I close this topic.